# Можно ли посмотреть файловую систему в завершённом контейнере docker

Tags: docker

К примеру у меня есть контейнер со статусом `Exited`. Во время выполнения в контейнер был сохранён файл. Можно ли его посмотреть, если статус контейнера `Exited`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно скопировать файл из контейнера на хост при помощи команды: `docker cp`:

```
docker cp test:/1.txt ./1.txt
```

где `test` это имя контейнера, `:/1.txt` - путь внутри контейнера, ./1.txt - куда скопиросать.

Также можно просто перейти в папку содержащую изменения, которые сделал контейнер во время работы. Выполнить команду:

```
docker container inspect <container_name>
```

Она выдаст, что-то вроде:

```json
"GraphDriver": {
    "Data": {
        "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1ad4f5983fa2a643a869be05d990ec548c30b361732f5ad371c405bb49a10f97-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0f58f0b4668fe6750d05e764bd3795909ca991ba8112e9316d9fd0c79000673c/diff",
        "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1ad4f5983fa2a643a869be05d990ec548c30b361732f5ad371c405bb49a10f97/merged",
        "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1ad4f5983fa2a643a869be05d990ec548c30b361732f5ad371c405bb49a10f97/diff",
        "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1ad4f5983fa2a643a869be05d990ec548c30b361732f5ad371c405bb49a10f97/work"
    },
    "Name": "overlay2"
},
```

Перейдя по пути указанном в `UpperDir`, вы поподете в root папку контейнера, а там можно найти и файл, который он создал.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! В гугл не увидела такого объяснения!